# UNION ALL truncates string values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Table B which has a column called EAN. Within the EAN column, there are string entries. I have another Table C with the exact column structure and with the EAN column also with string entries.

When I try to `UNION ALL` Table C to Table B (with Table C being "higher up" in the UNION ALL query), the resulting EAN column has all the entries originating from Table B truncated but not any of those originating from Table C.

For example, prior to the UNION ALL, Table B's EAN column has an entry `666151010628` but post operation this ends up being `666151000000`

I don't understand why this is?

The full query is as follows:

```
SELECT

   Year                                                                                        
  ,Week
  ,Supplier    

  ,Stock_Tracker


  ,EAN
  ,ASIN
  ,Name
  ,CostPrice_Local
  ,NULL as ShippingCost_Local
  ,CostPrice_GBP
  ,NULL as ShippingCost_GBP
  ,CostPrice_Local + 0 as LandedCostPrice_Local
  ,CostPrice_GBP + 0 as LandedCostPrice_GBP
  ,Qty_Invoiced
  ,Qty_Received
  ,Qty_Received - Qty_Invoiced as Qty_Delta

  ,Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_Local as InvoicedValue_Local
  ,Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_GBP as InvoicedValue_GBP

  ,Qty_Received*CostPrice_Local as ReceivedValue_Local
  ,Qty_Received*CostPrice_GBP as ReceivedValue_GBP

  ,(Qty_Received-Qty_Invoiced)*CostPrice_Local as Shortage_Delta_Local
  ,(Qty_Received-Qty_Invoiced)*CostPrice_GBP as Shortage_Delta_GBP

  ,(Qty_Received*CostPrice_Local)-(Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_Local) as Overall_Delta_Local
  ,(Qty_Received*CostPrice_GBP)-(Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_GBP) as Overall_Delta_GBP

  ,NULL as Status
  ,Run_Time


  FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_stock_tracker_2022` 

  WHERE CONCAT(Year, Supplier) IS NOT NULL

  
  
  UNION ALL 

  
  
  SELECT 


  Year
  ,Week
  ,Supplier
  ,Stock_Tracker 
  ,EAN
  ,ASIN
  ,Name
  ,CostPrice_Local
  ,ShippingCost_Local 
  ,CostPrice_GBP
  ,ShippingCost_GBP 
  ,LandedCostPrice_Local 
  ,LandedCostPrice_GBP 
  ,Qty_Invoiced
  ,Qty_Received
  ,Qty_Received - Qty_Invoiced as Qty_Delta

  ,Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_Local as InvoicedValue_Local
  ,Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_GBP as InvoicedValue_GBP

  ,Qty_Received*CostPrice_Local as ReceivedValue_Local
  ,Qty_Received*CostPrice_GBP as ReceivedValue_GBP

  ,(Qty_Received-Qty_Invoiced)*CostPrice_Local as Shortage_Delta_Local
  ,(Qty_Received-Qty_Invoiced)*CostPrice_GBP as Shortage_Delta_GBP

  ,(Qty_Received*CostPrice_Local)-(Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_Local) as Overall_Delta_Local
  ,(Qty_Received*CostPrice_GBP)-(Qty_Invoiced*CostPrice_GBP) as Overall_Delta_GBP

  ,Status
  ,Run_Time

  FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_stock_tracker_2023` 

  WHERE CONCAT(Year, Supplier) IS NOT NULL



  UNION ALL



  SELECT * FROM `strange-bird-366417.financial_data.tbl_qogita_data_dump_2022_v2` --adding in pre WK41 Qogita orders (from Jan-Sep 2022)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a minimized reproducer? (CREATE TABLE, INSERT, the SELECT.)

Comment: This is very hard to believe that EAN is stored as string on both tables and that merely unioning them together causes the last 6 characters of the string to be replaced with the character `0`.

Comment: If you give table B and table C definition, perhaps you will get an answer. Out of curiosity, I'll assume, EAN column defined as STRUCT<int64,int64> for EAN code like ``LLLLLLRRRRRR`` left and right parts of code.

Comment: Please don’t link to external documents - update your question with all relevant information, as editable text

Comment: The query I am using is basically doing TABLE 1 UNION ALL TABLE 2 UNION ALL TABLE 3. I have added screenshots above that show the EAN field in all three is of string format. Above I have also includes my full SQL code.